# Put text inside a textarea in a webview

Tags: java, android, webview, textarea

I need to put a value in a textarea of a website in a webview.

So I tried several things :

- get the textarea with javascript : something like `webview1.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].children[0]
  ....` But the desired textarea is in a iframe, and I don't know how to access it.
- Put a setOnTouchListener on my webview and paste from clipboard the desired value, but I don't know how to simulate a CTRL+V
- Parse the website with Jsoup, but I cannot get the html after authenticaton ([Jsoup authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384534/jsoup-authentication-failed))

Any other ideas ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452871/how-can-i-access-iframe-elements-with-javascript

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('table')[5].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0] is my Iframe, but no access to the Inside :-(