# Override existing Javascript function in a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, webview, textarea

I display a webpage (not mine) in a webview. There is a Textarea, in which I need to put some text.

```
<TEXTAREA NAME="app1" ROWS="3" style="width:95%" TABINDEX="1" 
onKeyDown="javascript:return gerTouch(event);"
onKeyUp="javascript:verif(app1,300,true);"
onBlur="javascript:effacer();">TEXT TO CHANGE</TEXTAREA>
```

Is it possible, with addJavascriptInterface, to rewrite the existing onKeyDown (or another one) function, in order to put my text in the desired place ?

Something like :

```
webview1.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
        {
            public void verif(String strl,int i,boolean b)
           {
              //Some code ?
           }
        }, "ok");
```

The textarea's name changes at each loading, and I cannot access the html textarea with another way.
Any other suggestion would be welcome :-) (my goal: put a value in a webview's textarea : [Put text inside a textarea in a webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411358/put-text-inside-a-textarea-in-a-webview))

Answer (score 1):

You can change the verif function by running something like after the webview has loaded (call it inside the onPageFinished() of your WebViewClient) :

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:window.verif = function(strl,i,b){/*some code*/}");
```

Comment: I put this : webview1.loadUrl("javascript:window.verif = function(strl,i,b){alert(strl);}"); in my onPageFinished, but no display.

Comment: @StéphaneGROSSMANN The JS `alert` function does nothing by default in Android webviews, you need to implement the method `onJsAlert` in a `WebChromeClient` to be able to handle alerts (create an AlertDialog with your message for example).

Comment: Ok thanks, but webview1.loadUrl("javascript:window.verif = function(strl,i,b){strl.value='test';}"); neither does something.

Comment: @StéphaneGROSSMANN maybe called to soon. You can retard it with an `Handler` field where you have your webview object and doing something like :
`handler.post(new Runnable() {public void run() {webView.loadUrl("javascript:...");}});` in your `WebViewClient.onPageFinished`

Comment: I tryed in Chromes's Console to rewrite the function 'verif', with window.verif=function(champTA, nbCarac, deuxLignes){};, but the old one is always working (deleting text if to much characters)